# Databricks jobs support file based trigger

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

We would like know if we using Databricks jobs instead ADF for orchestration, we might have to check if databricks jobs support file based trigger. kindly advise.

ultimately goal is, we have different ADF  environment and subscription, we know that the subscription and environment does not a issues to stop our goal.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

There will be upcoming feature to trigger jobs based on the file events.  It was mentioned in the latest [Databricks quarterly roadmap webinar](https://www.databricks.com/p/webinar/productroadmapwebinar) that you can watch.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that . But in ADF you do have the support for file based trigger and also that ADF has a notebook activity . You can stich these together .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook